# Java application hangs with strange GC Log

Tags: java, performance, memory, garbage-collection

My application started with Xms=1g, Xmx=2g. (Environment: JDK 8, Centos 7, 8G Ram, VMware)
I set up the log for GC and today I get the strange log:

```
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 267264K->267254K(308224K)] [ParOldGen: 1398111K->1398111K(1398272K)] 1665375K->1665365K(1706496K)
```

...

```
[Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 267264K->267254K(308224K)] [ParOldGen: 1398111K->1398111K(1398272K)] 1665375K->1665365K(1706496K)
```

These lines are repeated many times in about 20 mins and after that CPU consumption is increased to 100%, the application hangs
I guess, in a normal way, this number (1706496K) should reach to 2g. What could be the reason keeping this total memory is the same for very long time? At this time, VM memory usage is approximately 60%.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Try to get a thread dump and determine what is taking so much of memory.

Comment: I would venture to guess that you have a memory leak. Both young gen and old gen are full. I'm surprised that you don't get a OutOfMemory Error. If you increase the heap, the same thing should happen after a longer while. Could you try that?

Comment: Our system run for a while, and I don't think there is a memory leak. It could be the high load. But Xmx = 2G compare to total is 1.7H, how could it meet this situation in the VM layer?

Comment: This is not strange. The heap memory is full, but the GC manages to free a tiny amount (10k) on each collection, just enough to let the application continue until the next GC cycle. So in the end, the application spends >90% (likely >99%) of its time in garbage collection. That’s the reason why some GC algorithms bail out with an `OutOfMemoryError` even if they can free memory, if they detect that they are spending too much time for a tiny amount (the errors with the “GC overhead limit exceeded” message). It could be that there is no memory leak and just using a bigger heap solves the issue.

Comment: The heap memory is not full, it still can allocate more memory because Xmx is declared as 2g while heap now is 1.7? Is there anything i miss here? Thanks